# Java: Trouble creating an array from file

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, bufferedreader, filereader

Hey I have this code here:

```
public class Levels {
boolean newGame = true;

public void newGame() {
    while (newGame) {
        int cLevel = 1;

        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

        try {
            BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(
                    "src/WordGuess/ReadFile/LevelFiles/Level_" + cLevel
                            + ".txt"));
            String cLine = bf.readLine();
            while (cLine != null) {
                list.add(cLine);
            }
            String[] words = new String[list.size()];
            words = list.toArray(words);
            for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
                System.out.println(words[i]);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out
                    .println("Oh! Something went terribly wrong. A team of highly trained and koala-fied koalas have been dispatched to fix the problem. If you dont hear from them please restart this program.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}}
```

And it gives me this error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
>       at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.ArrayList.grow(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.ArrayList.ensureExplicitCapacity(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.ArrayList.ensureCapacityInternal(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.ArrayList.add(Unknown Source)
>       at WordGuess.ReadFile.SaveLoadLevels.Levels.newGame(Levels.java:24)
>       at Main.main(Main.java:29)

Can anyone help, please? Thank you!

Comment: What size is the file you are reading? java.lang.OutOfMemoryError is thrown when your computer runs out of memory because you are running really heavy programs in Java.

Comment: @migueljimenezz: In this case the length of the file is irrelevant, so long as there's at least one line - see my answer :)

Comment: Where is _newGame_ set to false? What I see here is an infinite loop!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the problem:

```
String cLine = bf.readLine();
while (cLine != null) {
    list.add(cLine);
}
```

You're not reading the next line in your loop (the value of `cLine` never changes) - so it's just going to loop forever. You want:

```
String line;
while ((line = bf.readLine()) != null) {
    list.add(line);
}
```

(And as noted in comments, this is also in an infinite outer loop because `newGame` will stay true forever...)

Comment: Alexis Lecrec G.S
Thank you, fellas! You are all correct! I haven't created my false statement and changed the while to if for now. And you really helped me with the readLine() statement. I thought the method reads through all the lines but now I figured it out. How dumb of me it says readLINE as in one line. Sorry to bother you with these simple stuff. I'm new to this if i can rate you please tell me how :) And if you can tell me if the structure of my code is good for a word guessing game for now that will be appreciated too. Thank you again!

Comment: Don't worry, we've all started with the simple stuff ;)

Answer (score 1):

You are reading one line and keep on adding it to list which is causing out of memory.
Modify your code as:

```
String cLine
while(cLine = bf.readLine() != null)
{
    list.add(cLine);
}
```